# CSS height auto have no height

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

In responsive video player there is no height of height auto elements and is not working as it should.
First, cover image should be over whole player and controls bar should be down. Like here:

[image: What like it should be]

There is no height of  so I can't put height: 100% because everything goes wild. If I put height 100% on cover image, it disappears. 
Controls bar is stick to the top and can't be moved. I've been working like this for a years and never head problem like this.

Here is my code:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6voy890/)

HTML

```
<section class="player">
    <video class="video">
        <source src="http://ridens.net/templates/default/player/videos/Ridens_promo_video_finish_mp4.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <div class="video_cover">
        <img src="http://ridens.net/templates/default/player/videos/promovideothumbnail.png">
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="controls_bar">

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.player {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.video {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.video_cover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 40;
}
.video_cover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.controls {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 60;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.controls_bar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 70;
    left: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `CSS height auto have no height` Perhaps because the computed value of `auto` is `0` in that particular case.

Comment: We can't inspect or debug images...

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to add code.

Comment: @HashemQolami But it should take height of child element.

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is with `position:absolute` Because your positioning is absolute, its height is not included in the parent element, so setting height:auto returns a height of 0 because there is no height. If you want the black bar to cover the image, you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery to get the image's width and height, and set it to the black bar. If I understood your question correctly, this should help you, if not let me know and I'll see if I can provide you with any further explanations/answers/comments/ideas/whatever you want to call this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo with play functionality](http://jsbin.com/wovaz/8/edit)**

Don't use the `<img>` tag, rather use a responsive `cover` background-image for the `.video_cover`

```
<div class="video_cover"></div> <!-- Tada! no image! -->
```

**All you need**: (AKA: *Total CSS remake*):

```
.player { position: relative; }
.video { width: 100%; }
.video_cover {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(coverimage.png) 50% / cover;
}
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

If you need it here's the full HTML:

```
<section class="player">

  <video class="video">
    <source src="promo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>

  <div class="video_cover"></div>

  <div class="controls">
    <div class="controls_bar">
      <span id="play"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

and jQuery:

```
var $pla = $('.player');
var $vid = $('.video');
var $cov = $('.video_cover');
var $con = $('.controls');

$con.hide();

$pla.hover(function(){
  $con.stop().slideToggle(250);
});

$('#play').html("&#9658;").click(function(){
  var pp = this.pp ^= 1;
  $(this).html(pp?"&#9616;&#9616;":"&#9658;");
  $cov.fadeToggle(700, function(){
    $vid[0][pp?"play":"pause"]();
  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfect. Hvala :D